# Glacier retrieval notification of s3 objects

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have some s3 buckets which send their objects to glacier after x days of creation. When I go to retrieve those objects on the s3 interface, I need to keep reloading page to see when restoration has finished so object is ready for download.

I'd like to have s3 send an sns notification when that restoration is finished so object is ready.

You can configure that on glacier vault notifications tab, but you can't on s3.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can not. I have been waiting for months to have this feature but, for some mysterious reason AWS does not implement it.

Comment: Has this changed yet??? I read some docs that made it sound possible but the docs do not make it clear. We are 4+ years later I sure hope this exists

Comment: It looks like, after all these years, AWS finally enabled S3 event notifications for ObjectRestore event type. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html